# asp.net wizard control non-clickable sidebar

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

I have an asp.net wizard, and I want the user to navigate the control only with the next/previous buttons.

Anyway, I would like to set the sidebar so that it displays the step names with the current step highlighted, but without letting the user click on them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `SideBarTemplate` and set the `Enabled` attribute of the links to `False`:

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" DisplaySideBar="true">
    <SideBarTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="SideBarButton" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="SideBarButton" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="currentStep" />
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </SideBarTemplate>
    ...
</asp:Wizard>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as possible!